Off Policy TD(0) Derivation
In Sutton and Barto's book on RL, it says

The ratio $\rho_{t:T-1}$ transforms the returns to have the right expected value:
$$\mathbf{E}[\rho_{t:T-1} G_t | S_t = s] = v_\pi (s).\tag{5.4}$$

The book just mentions this much but I would like a proof of this fact which is not too complex, wikipedia article on Importance Sampling is too abstract for me.
After this the book also asks us

$\textit{Exercise 6.7 }$ Design an off-policy version of the TD(0) update that can be used with arbitrary target policy $\pi$ and covering behavior policy $b$, using at each step $t$ the importance sampling ratio $\rho_{t:t}$ $(5.3)$.

I found a solution online which also confuses me. Particularly can someone please elaborate using summations and basic definitions as to how the exercise and equation 5.4 is derived.

Since we know that $\mathbb{E}_b[G_t|S_t=s]=v_b(s)$, and the importance sampling ratio $\rho_{t:T-1}$ focuses on reweighting the trajectories under the behavior policy $b$ to account for the difference between $b$ and the target policy $\pi$, which is defined via the action probabilities only of a trajectory under the two policies as shown in (5.3).
The key idea here is that the environment's reward distribution given a state-action pair is independent of any policy, so simply via the importance sampling ration $\rho_{t:T-1}$ (which is the only difference between the two policies affecting their value function as averaged trajectory return w.r.t. their policy) reweighting a generic trajectory under $b$, we can adjust the value function of $b$ correctly for $\pi$. Therefor we can arrive at $v_{\pi}(s)=\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[G_t|S_t=s]=\mathbb{E}_b[\rho_{t:T-1} G_t|S_t=s]$ immediately, and the authors didn't bother to explain further.
Further off-policy TD(0) derivation based on previous result is as follows, note that we have $\rho_{t:T-1}=\rho_{t:t}\rho_{t+1:T-1}$ by above definition (5.3):
\begin{align*}
v_{\pi}(s) &= \mathbb{E}_b[\rho_{t:T-1} G_t|S_t=s] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_b[\rho_{t:T-1} R_{t+1} + \gamma \rho_{t:T-1} G_{t+1}|S_t=s] \\
&= \rho_{t:t}\mathbb{E}_b[R_{t+1}|S_t=s] + \gamma \rho_{t:t} \mathbb{E}_b[\rho_{t+1:T-1} G_{t+1}|S_{t+1}=s_{t+1}] \\
&= \rho_{t:t}(\mathbb{E}_b[R_{t+1}|S_t=s] + \gamma \mathbb{E}_b[\rho_{t+1:T-1} G_{t+1}|S_{t+1}=s_{t+1}]) \\
&= \rho_{t:t}(r(s, A_t) + \gamma v_{\pi}(s_{t+1}))
\end{align*}
Finally according to TD(0) update rule, you just need to use the experienced reward $R_{t+1}$ and the bootstrap estimate counterpart of the above RHS target policy $\pi$'s value function $V(S_{t+1})$ at time $t+1$ as the temporally updated value for the bootstrap estimate of target policy $\pi$'s value function $V(S_t)$ at time $t$ for state $s=S_t$.

how did 3rd equality come from the second equality in td(0) and how does importance sample reweighting work, like why not log (importance sampling ratio), why do these things not work aka can you mathematically show that v_pi uses importance sampling

The 3rd step in above off-policy TD(0) derivation is ultimately from the intuition that the cumulative return $G_{t+1}$ doesn't depend on $S_t$ but only on $S_{t+1}$ due to the the famous Markov property of the environment's MDP, and the reward $R_{t+1}$ only depend on $S_t$ and the action chosen $A_t$ at time $t$, so only the ratio $ρ_{t:t}$ at time $t$ takes real reweighting effect for the target policy and remains.

There's no gradient update involved here for state value function of either base or target policy, unlike in policy-gradient theorem to update the policy parameters, so there're no log needed at all. Importance sampling ratio as a ratio is purely used for reweighting the cumulative return $G_t$ from any time $t$ of a generic trajectory under the base policy to correctly account for the state value function under the target policy as already explained in the 2nd paragraph of my answer above, which is intuitive. You just intuit about $ρ_{t:T−1}$ and relation between $v_π(s)$ and $v_b(s)$.

hmm, ok but that can't "prove" the correctness right? for correctness mathematical proof is needed not the intuition so mentioned, i am asking for that proof if you can write it please

Perhaps one more math step expansion for your purpose here could be tried, you can expand the Expectation operator $\mathbb{E}$ using more familiar summation algebra if you like, ie, $$v_π(s)=\mathbb{E}π[G_t|S_t=s]=\sum{τ}P_π(τ∣S_t=s)G_t(τ)=\sum_{τ}P_b(τ∣S_t=s)ρ_{t:T−1}G_t(τ)=\mathbb{E}b[ρ{t:T−1}G_t|S_t=s]$$, where $τ$ is a generic trajectory under the target policy $π$. But if you're very familiar with the definition of $\mathbb{E}$ in statistics, you don't need to replace with probability distribution and replace back later on. Hope it clarified your lingering confusion for this post.

Ok thanks, this clear my confusion for deriviation of 5.4. But for TD(0) how is $$\mathbb{E}[\rho_{t:T-1}R_{t+1}|S_t=s] =\sum_{a} b(a|s) \sum_{s',r} p(s',r)r\prod_{k=t}^{T-1} \frac{\pi(A_k|S_k)}{b(A_k|S_k)} = \sum_{a} \pi(a|s) \sum_{s',r} p(s',r)r\prod_{k=t+1}^{T-1} \frac{\pi(A_k|S_k)}{b(A_k|S_k)} = \mathbb{E_\pi}[\rho_{t+1:T-1} R_{t+1}|S_t=s] $$
How do we get $ \rho_{t:t} \mathbb{E}b[R{t+1}|S_t=s]$
Sorry if i am missing something obvious

Recall that in model-free TD(0) RL, $R _{t+1}$ is simply observed, not computed as you tried above. Since $R _{t+1}$ only depends on $S_t$ and $A_t$ (Markov Property) and $R {t+1}$ is just one-step reward (not multi-step cumulative return), so the expectation of the one-step reward $R {t+1}$ doesn’t depend on the future importance sampling action ratios $ρ{t+1:T−1}$ starting from $t+1$. The other cumulative part $G{t+1}$ is different so all future ratios still apply to reweight it under behavior policy $b$ as reflected in your already fully understood equation (5.4). Hope it clarifies now

But since the future importance sampling ratio is multiplied to $R_{t+1}$ in the equation on 2nd equation it changes the result? Like multiplying something by 1/2 changes expectation to 1/2 of the previous result, so how did $\rho_{t+1:T-1}$ vanish in 3rd equality. my main issue with 3rd equality is how did $\rho_{t+1:T-1}$ vanish at 3rd equality, i understand that $R_{t+1}$ does not depend on future

The future importance sampling ratio $ρ_{t+1:T−1}$ multiplies $R_{t+1}$ in the second equality of my answer due to first time substitution. But it doesn’t affect the expectation of $R_{t+1}$ under the trajectory by policy $b$ due to the conditional independence I've emphasized, so you can drop  $ρ_{t+1:T−1}$ in the 3rd step. Again this may be not intuitive enough for you, and you can always think in terms of summation algebra with $P_b(τ)R_{t+1}$ like before and the trajectory $τ$ matters for expectation of the one-step $R_{t+1}$ is just $(s_t, A_t)$ which should only be weighted by $ρ_{t:t}$.

Another way to prove is due to conditional independence you can factor out like $\mathbb{E}b[ρ{t+1:T−1}ρ_{t:t}R_{t+1}|s_t=s]=\mathbb{E}b[ρ{t+1:T−1}|s_t=s]\mathbb{E}b[ρ{t:t}R_{t+1}|s_t=s]$, then you expand $\mathbb{E}b[ρ{t+1:T−1}|s_t=s]$ using summation algebra with term $b(A_{t+1}|S_{t+1})P(S_{t+2}|S_{t+1},A_{t+1})ρ_{t+1:T−1}=\pi(A_{t+1}|S_{t+1})P(S_{t+2}|S_{t+1},A_{t+1})ρ_{t+2:T−1}=...$, so finally you get $\mathbb{E}b[ρ{t+1:T−1}|s_t=s]=\sum_τP_{\pi}(τ)=1$. Hope this helps.

oh ok thanks for this, just to make sure i get it, that importance sampling when the summations are performed is assumed to be of that trajectory i.e. for eg  $\mathbb{E_b} [\rho_{t:t}|S_t=s] = \sum_{a} b(a|s) \frac{\pi(A_t|S_t)}{b(A_t|S_t)} = \sum_{a} \pi(a|s) = 1$ here we could write it as $\pi(a|s)$ because we assume importance sampling is a variable which is calculated for each possible trajectory right?

"that importance sampling when the summations are performed is assumed to be of that trajectory", yes, trajectory $τ$ is the only r.v. you can count on here to replace expectation of value functions or any other functions with summation involving $P(τ)$ in terms of either policy $b$ or the target policy. Any time confused you can always do this replacement to clear out.
